# Find earliest and latest dates of specified records from a table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table (in MS SQL 2005) with a selection of dates. I want to be able to apply a WHERE statement to return a group of them and then return which date is the earliest from one column and which one is the latest from another column. Here is an example table:

```
ID StartDate  EndDate    Person
1  01/03/2010 03/03/2010 Paul
2  12/05/2010 22/05/2010 Steve
3  04/03/2101 08/03/2010 Paul
```

So I want to return all the records where Person = 'Paul'. But return something like (earliest ) StartDate = 01/03/2010 (from record ID 1) and (latest) EndDate = 08/03/2010 (from record ID 3).

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might want to build in a check that your start date cannot be after the end date. (row 3)

Comment: Not to worry, it was a typo and validation is done on data entry. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need the `min` and `max` aggregate functions, e.g. a very simple case:

```
select min(StartDate), max(EndDate)
from data
where Person = 'Paul'
```

You have all the usual power of SQL, so selection from a sub-query is available.

Comment: Thanks Richard, so obvious now!

Answer (score 3):

It would be neat to use a `group by` as well. So If you like all the persons in your result, and you leave out the where clause, you wouldn't get erroneous data:

```
select person, min(StartDate), max(EndDate)
from data
group by person
```

or

```
select person, min(StartDate), max(EndDate)
from data
where person ='Paul'
group by person
```

or

```
select person, min(StartDate), max(EndDate)
from data
group by person
having person ='Paul'
```